# Выбрать наиболее оптимальную структуру для хранения и поиска данных по значению(С++)

Tags: c++, память, производительность, структуры-данных

Всем добрый день. Помогите пожалуйста определится: какая структура данных в языке С++ наиболее оптимально подойдет для хранения **большого количества** десятизначных целых положительных чисел, если подразумевается только хранение этих чисел в выбранной структуре и поиск числа по значению. Важно , чтобы выбранная структура данных занимала как можно меньше объема памяти. Количество чисел 100'000'000'. Диапазон значений элемента - [0, 9 999 999 999].Добавление/удаление элемента не предусматривается.Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Обычный отсортированный массив?... Поиск O(log N), память N - минимальная, ни байта на служебные расходы :)

Comment: "только хранение" - массив. быстро искать - отсортировать и бин поиском

Comment: Большого количества - это сколько? И в каком диапазоне числа? Нужно ли уметь добавлять числа или достаточно начальной инициализации, а дальше только чтение?

Comment: Диапазон чисел от 0 до 9 999 999 999. Количество 100 000 000. Добавлять/удалять/изменять элементы уметь не нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если "*Добавлять/удалять/изменять не нужно*" - теоретически можно использовать идеальное хеширование, тогда к минимальному объему добавится максимально быстрый поиск... Но это достаточно сложный путь.

Так что, думаю, проще всего - обычный массив. Только вот для представления такого диапазона чисел нужно 34 бита, так что обычного 4-байтового числа не хватит. Если память **критична** - можно соорудить 5-байтовые числа, и занять примерно 477 мегабайт. Если же 763 мегабайта - некритично, то можно воспользоваться массивом 8-байтовых `unsigned long long`. Вариант с упаковкой битов от разных чисел, чтоб использовать только 405 мегабайт, не рассматриваем - можно, но слишком сложно, будет тормозить поиск.

Можно разбить на 4 массива, в которых хранить по 4 младших байта чисел, а номер массива от 0 до 3 - это старшие 2 бита. Получится неплохая экономия, до 382 мегабайт...

Конечно же, для применения бинарного поиска массив должен быть отсортирован.

Можно использовать `array` - он не добавляет накладных расходов на косвенное обращение.

Comment: А не получится ли переполнение стэка, если я буду использовать для такого количества элементов std::array?)

Comment: А вы его хотите сделать в стеке? Ну, можно попросить соответствующий стек, или разместить в глобальной памяти, или создать динамический массив(ы). Понятно, что при обычных стандартных размерах стека толку не будет. Но это уже не зависит от самого типа. В принципе, можно использовать `vector`, но с явным указанием размера - чтоб он не выделил памяти больше, чем надо (ну, тут вы должны верить в корректность его реализации :))

Comment: 4 массива -- отличная идея. Если же известно, что маленьких чисел много, то для них можно дополнительно использовать *битовый массив* (один бит на число)

Answer (score 1):

Если количество чисел заранее известно, то `std::array`. Если нет ― `std::vector`.